# Cannot apply Custom Object to bone - Blender 2.92

Tags: rigging

I added a bone to my scene and wanted to apply a Custom Object (Bone properties -> Viewport Display -> Custom Shape ->Custom Object)

But I can't seem to apply it. I tried it in Pose Mode and object mode but nothing happens.

If I open a new file with the standard cube, add an armature and and then apply a Custom Object to the single bone, it works, but in my recent full file it doesn't work.

Is there something I overlooked?

Comment: You may need to allow custom shapes on the armature as well.  Enable shapes in properties/armature/viewport display.

Comment: Worked!! Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  For me, the solution was in the Armature Data, 'Viewport Display' sub-menu.  The 'Shapes' property must be checked for custom bone shapes to work properly.

[image]

Good luck...